# SQL query written in ASP.NET (code behind is VB) not providing results expected

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

Below is a portion of my code behind in an ASP.NET app, the code behind is visual basic.  When providerOfficeQuery is run it is not providing the expected results.  You can see the portion of the database that the query is using:

```
67          RUMINJO, ANNE MD    CHAPEL HILL - PROVIDENCE RD     chapelhillProvidenceRDArrayList
68          RUSSO, FRANK FNP-BC ASHEVILLE - RIDGEFIELD BLVD ashevilleRidgefieldBLVDArrayList
69          SAWYER, LOUIS PHD   DURHAM COUNSELING CENTER    durhamCounselingCenterArrayList
70          SAWYER, LOUIS PHD   DURHAM - SHANNON RD durhamShannonRDArrayList
71          SCHIAPPA, JENNIFER LCSW CARY COUNSELING CENTER  caryCounselingCenterArrayList
```

I'm sorry for the formatting, the fields are ID, PROVIDER, OFFICE, OFFICE_ARRAY_LIST respectively.

When providerName equals "SAWYER, LOUIS PHD", I expect the query to produce two results, both row 69 and 70 and subsequently to provide me with office "DURHAM COUNSELING CENTER" and "DURHAM - SHANNON RD", yet when the query is run what actually occurs is that I end up with "DURHAM COUNSELING CENTER" twice.  I have verified this with adding the results to a ListBox to verify the results.

I'm not an expert and I have scoured Google and various forums and cannot find why this isn't producing the expected results.  Any thoughts, anyone?

Thanks.

```
            ' find the Provider's office and add it to the ListBox
        Dim providerOfficeQuery = From populateItem In db.Sheet3_
                                  Where populateItem.PROVIDER = providerName
                                  Select populateItem

        For Each x In providerOfficeQuery

            providerInfoOffice = x.OFFICE

            If providerInfoOffice = "ASHEVILLE - DOCTOR'S PARK" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CAROLINA PARTNERS OF CENTRAL ASHEVILLE")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "ASHEVILLE - RIDGEFIELD BLVD" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CAROLINA PARTNERS OF SOUTH ASHEVILLE")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "CARY - E CHATHAM ST" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CPMH AFFILIATE: CARY - DONNA PARRISH")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "CARY - KILDAIRE FARM RD" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CPMH AFFILIATE: CARY - JENNY TART")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "CARY - SE CARY PKWY" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CAROLINA PARTNERS OF CARY")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "CARY COUNSELING CENTER" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CARY COUNSELING CENTER")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "CHAPEL HILL - FRANKLIN ST" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CPMH AFFILIATE: CHAPEL HILL - DANA BENNISON")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "CHAPEL HILL - PROVIDENCE RD" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CAROLINA PARTNERS Of CHAPEL HILL")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "CHARLOTTE" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CAROLINA PARTNERS OF CONCORD")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "DURHAM - BROAD ST" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CPMH AFFILIATE: DURHAM - SARAH DAWSON")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "DURHAM - NEW HOPE COURT" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CAROLINA PARTNERS AT NEW HOPE COURT")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "DURHAM - SHANNON RD" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CAROLINA PARTNERS AT SHANNON RD")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "DURHAM COUNSELING CENTER" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("DURHAM COUNSELING CENTER")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "NORTH RALEIGH COUNSELING CENTER" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("NORTH RALEIGH COUNSELING CENTER")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "RALEIGH - DRESSER COURT" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CAROLINA PARTNERS OF RALEIGH")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "RALEIGH - NEUROPSYCH CLINIC" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("THE NEUROPSYCH CLINIC")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "RALEIGH - RALEIGH ANNEX" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CAROLINA PARTNERS RALEIGH ANNEX")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "RALEIGH - WELLNESS CENTER" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("THE WELLNESS CENTER")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "WAKE FOREST - CAPCOM AVE" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("CAROLINA PARTNERS OF WAKE FOREST")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "WAKE FOREST - WFCC" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("WAKE FOREST COUNSELING CENTER")
            ElseIf providerInfoOffice = "WILSON - NASH ST" Then
                providerInfoListBox.Items.Add("WILSON PSYCHIATRIC ASSOCIATES A CAROLINA PARTNERS PRACTICE")
            End If

            providerInfoOffice = Nothing

        Next
```

Comment: Put a break point at Dim providerOfficeQuery line and see what you get for office.

Comment: I did and I get two results, and both are "DURHAM COUNSELING CENTER".

Comment: Are you using EF? what is db.Sheet3_? check your record in DB again make sure they have different offices

Comment: Yes I am using an entityFramework, db is part of my "using" statement and Sheet3_ is the specific table to be used for this query.  I am positive they have different offices, the portion of my database above is a copy and paste directly from Sheet3_.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
Dim ResultCount = provierOfficeQuery.Count()
```

and outputting that value of ResultCount for the "DURHAM COUNSELING CENTER" case to make sure that you are actually getting the two results returned.

If it is not two, then you have to look at your source data as mentioned by Zaki. For example, one of the records for SAWYER, LOUIS PHD may have an extra space or something in the PROVIDER field.

Comment: I did as advised and verified that I am indeed getting two results and both results are "DURHAM COUNSELING CENTER".  The thought that there might be a spelling error or extra space had occurred to me, as I have made that error in the past, but it is not the case this time.  This makes no sense to me at all?!?

Comment: I just figured out what the issue was.  The model that was created when I made the entityFramework was never updated, so when the query was run, it was using old information from the table definition.  Which did not include the ID column.  Now that the model has been updated, I am receiving the results as expected.  And I'm sorry if I am not using the appropriate keywords to explain what was going on.